# Why is it stupid to create custom PDO query handlers?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

According to this thread: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29362/very-simple-php-pdo-class people generally say it's stupid to create custom PDO query handlers, which I find very hard to understand.

For instance, in my projects I prefer to have a class / function to do things I do all the time, quicker for me.

For instance, when you need to perform simple updates in a table, I have created this function, which I use all the time:

```
function UpdateData($table, $data, $where, $params=array()) {
    $sql = 'UPDATE `' . tbl_prefix.$table . '` SET ';
        foreach($data as $name => $value) {
            $params[':' . $name] = $value;
            $runs++;
            $sql .= "`$name` = :" . $name;

            if(end($data) !== $value) // if not last run
                $sql .= ',';
        }

    if(!is_array($where)) {
        $sql .= ' ' . $where; // insert where clause
    } else {
        // Array format can be used
        $sql .= ' WHERE';

        foreach($where as $argument => $value) {
            $params[':where_'.$argument] = $value;

            $num++;
            $sql .= " `" . $argument . "` = :where_" . $argument . " ";

            if(end($where) !== $value)
                $sql .= ' AND';
        }
    }

    $query = doQuery($sql, $params); // do the update

    if($query)
        return true;
}
```

And the `doQuery` (which I also use when I want to query database):

```
function doQuery($query, $params=array()) {
    global $db;
    try {
        $result = $this->$db->prepare($query);
        $result->execute($params);
        $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $result;
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        $real_query = $query;
        foreach($params as $name => $value) {
            $real_query = str_replace($name, '\''.$value.'\'', $real_query);
        }

        SystemLog($ex->GetMessage(), array('real_query' => $real_query, 'query' => $query), 1); // log error
    }

    return false;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this? I find it extremely useful.

*some code have been taken out of the scripts to simplify the code*

Comment: If it's useful to you then go for it. You have created a utility that you reuse in your projects, so that negates the accepted answer's argument about reusability. While I get what he's saying, he may be referring to creating a massive abstraction class or something and not just a couple helper methods. Either way, your project should fit your needs. If you know enough about this stuff to have even made those 2 helpers above then you're probably safe in using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're doing is fine. The main argument in that thread is that you miss out on Prepared statements: I've been using SQL since about 1984 and DBMS's have been good enough that using a Prepared statement makes no real difference since probably 1994. I haven't used one for over 20 years and my systems do perform properly.

Still, everybody has their own opinion. I've done what you do many times and never had a problem with it. Nowadays I use ORM's which means I don't have to do that either.

Comment: I believe, most of PHP developers use prepared statements because of higher security, am I wrong?

Comment: It's got nothing to do with security! Prepared statements a 'pre-compiled'. Back in the old days compiling - working out the query plan - was quite a large overhead so you could do it once and not have to suffer it again. This is not the case nowadays. Not using Prepared statements also gets around the problem with skewed data distributions where the actual values in the where clauses might make different plans better.

Comment: Actually, with PHP and PDO I take that back. It seems that with MySQL Prepare is required to bind parameters (after a quick look at trhe docs), and its using parameters that add security against SQL Injection. Sorry about that! (That isn't required for other DBMS's)

Answer (score 0):

In my previous project I had setup a couple of functions for making SQL requests using PDO. They would cover most cases: basic inserts, basic updates, basic deletes, etc.

If you implement it well enough, using PDO, prepared statements and catch Exceptions, then you should be fine, and you get the best of both worlds, simple usage and higher security of PDO prepared statements.

I never had a problem. You just need to make sure you implement it perfectly though.

Answer (score -3):

Only things i can find that adds value is PDO is good for handling large data passing it trough javascript/php website (would not work right with MySqli!) and a few extra options/methods. as in any new language u need to take notes, dont think that all the big coders are running multi lang projects from their head. i dont think it is safer than MySqli either... i actually think it is unsafer then mysqli. (edit) and after few das of working with big data i found the security issue's that work better with PDO.. still on places where there is no direct access for the user to modify mysqli it is prob fine to use it. i guess we will find out in the future.

Comment: PDO and MySQLi are pretty interchangable if you implement each one properly. There is very, very few things PDO can do that MySQLi *can't* do. It's simply easier on PDO.

Comment: Mysqli with my Isam is way faster with large data then PDO there is a reason for it and u are missing my point. PDO can handle large data better in combination with html5 goodies, to create that responsive feel, that is all there is to it if u ask me. this is my own experience.

Comment: HTML5 has nothing to do with database interactions. You may be refering to AJAX requests?

Comment: Peter, you have answered a question that was asked, and was answered, 6 years ago. Yet your answers doesn't explain itself very well and (by my perception) your comments are vague generalisations and a "I know better than you" attitude, rather than trying to actually teach or impart any actual *knowledge* . It's great you know so much about what you do, but I would suggest you really work on conveying that rich vein of information in a more open and ceherent manor to make your answer worthwhile. Thanks.

Comment: Is it only me, or "PDO is good for handling large data" is rather opposite to "Mysqli with my Isam is way faster with large data"? Either way,  this stream of consciousness hardly counts as an answer.